# How to get the rotational value of an object JQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, css, image, rotation

I have a code to rotate and image back and forth based on YOffset. However, I want to know how to get the degrees that my image has been rotated and use that as my if statement.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var sdegree = 0; 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            sdegree = ( window.pageYOffset > 1000 ) ? sdegree + 4 : sdegree - 4;
            var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
            $(".plane").css({
            transform : srotate
        });
      });
    });   
</script>
```

What I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var sdegree = 0; 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            sdegree = ( //INSERT DEGREES that .plane has been rotated > 30deg )// ? sdegree + 4 : sdegree - 4;
            var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
            $(".plane").css({
                transform : srotate
            });
        });
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when you're getting the transform property back from the browser you'll receive the feared **Matrix**, and not the degrees ?

Comment: yuppp unfortunately :/

Comment: If it's just a condition to see if it was rotated -4 or +4, you could use a flag instead ?

Comment: don't know how flags work could you show me how i'm kinda new to this stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't `sdegree` tell you how many degrees it's rotated ?

Comment: I was wondering what the code would be to just use this (https://gist.github.com/wilhelm-murdoch/1492454#file-getpurerotation-js) to get the degrees

Comment: oh woah actually it might

Comment: IT WORKED yup sdegree works

Comment: how do i create it so its actually 0 < sdegree < 30 ?

Comment: What? zero is less than sdegree is less than 30? I don't get it!

Comment: maybe `sdegree > 0 && sdegree < 30`, it's more than 0, but less than 30 ?

Comment: is there anyway to mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: Not unless I post an actual answer! You can also post the final solution yourself, and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

I actually recently had to get the degrees rotated of an element as well. My method was similar to this:

```
function calculateAngle(element) {
    var tr = (window.getComputedStyle(element, null)).getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform"),
        values = tr.split("(")[1],
        values = values.split(")")[0],
        values = values.split(","),
        a = values[0],
        b = values[1],
        c = values[2],
        d = values[3],
        radians = Math.atan2(b, a);
    if (radians < 0) {
        radians += (2 * Math.PI);
    }
    return Math.round(radians * (180 / Math.PI));
}

var element = document.getElementById("rotate");
calculateAngle(element);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/5cU8p/3/)

You can then use whatever `if` statement you want based off of the angle.